# Reading out URL parameter using get_query_var (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm running a website where people get redirected after having bought a product on an external shop. The redirection link looks like this: www.mypage.com/thank-you/?order_id=ABCDE

I would like to read out the parameter "order_id" from the URL and found out that the best/safest way in WordPress would be using the native get_query_var function.

To register the variable "order_id" I already added the following code to my functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
$vars[] = "order_id";
return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Now I would like to be able to print the order_id in HTML but can't figure out how to do it. S.th. like

```
Order ID = <?php ... get_query_var( 'order_id' ) ... ?>
```

That should result in

```
Order ID = ABCDE
```

Any advice how to do it? I'm fairly new to php but it's not the first addition to my functions.php which has worked so far.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I implement that in the HTML code?

Comment: `<?php if (  get_query_var(  'order_id'  )  )  { ?>  <h2> Order ID  =  <?php echo get_query_var(  'order_id'  ); } ?> </h2>`

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't show anything: https://www.kettlebell-info.de/thank-you/?order_id=XYZ
Any further ideas where the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom template for thank-you page and then get that order_id param from the URL, and show in that template in PHP code like this:

```js
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Thankyou page
*/
get_header();

if($_GET['order_id']){
 $orderId = $_GET['order_id'];
}
?>
<div class="container">
 <h1>Thank you. Your order has been received.</h1>
 <h2>Order details:</h2>
 <span>Order Number: <?php echo $orderId; ?> </span>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```